# list index out of range when performing database queries in Hypothesis function

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, hypothesis-test, python-hypothesis

I'm using Python Hypothesis to write random tests for database. 
After 1-2 loops of insert the given values to the table I get list index out of range and @seed to reproduce. 
There is nothing that suppose to fail, I'm not asserting anything yet.
How can I debug this?

Thanks

```
        run_statement("create table t (x int)")
        @given(st.integers(1,10), st.integers(1,10))
        def insert_select(x):
            assume(x)
            run_statement("insert into t values ({})".format(x))
            select_results = run_statement_with_results("select * from t")
            print select_results

        insert_select()
```

results:

```
You can add @seed(257907719204305935240373390472712621009) to this test to reproduce this failure.
timeout
error: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this test is fundamentally broken:

- You are sharing database state between executions of your test case, which *must not* happen or your tests will be irreproducible.
- You are providing two arguments to `@given`, but the test function only accepts one.
- The `assume(x)` call is pointless, because `x` can never be falsey

Once those are fixed, the problem may well vanish.